# Is operator norm invariant under multiplication with orthonormal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $r \times r$ real matrix and $Q$ be a $n\times r$ matrix whose columns are orthonormal. I know that $||QA||_2 = ||A||_2$ because $$||QA||_2 = \max_{||x||_2=1} ||QAx||_2\,= \,\max_{||x||_2=1}x^TA^TQ^TQAx\, = \, \max_{||x||_2=1} x^TA^TAx \,=\, ||A||_2$$
I also know that $||AQ^T||_2\leq ||A||_2||Q^T||_2 = ||A||_2$.

My question: Is $||AQ^T||_2 \,=\, ||A||_2$?

Here is my partial attempt: 
$$||AQ^T||_2 = \max_{||x||_2=1} {||AQ^Tx||} \text{over } x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ and $$||A||_2 = \max_{||y||_2=1} {||Ay||} \text{over }y \in \mathbb{R}^r$$

Let maxima occur at $x^*$ and $y^*$. As Column Space of $Q^T = \mathbb{R}^r$, $\exists x \,s.t.\, Q^Tx = y^*$ but $||x|| \neq 1$. So, we have to find solution of $Q^Tx = y^*$ constrained to $||x||=1$. Can it be shown that such a solution will or will not exist?

Comment: If you know that $\|QA\|_2=\|A\|_2$ for all $Q$ with orthonormal columns, then you also know this for $Q^T$, as it has orthonormal columns.

Comment: As Q is $n\times r$, $Q^T$ doesn't necessarily have orthonormal columns. I think we can proceed by observing that for any matrix $M$, $||M||_2 = ||M^T||_2$, therefore $||AQ^T||_2 = ||(QA^T)^T||_2 = ||QA^T||_2 = ||A^T||_2 = ||A||_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument you suggest in the comments will work. To continue with the method you begin in your question, let $v_1, \dots, v_r$ be the columns of $Q$, and let $e_1, \dots, e_r$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb R^r$.

If $y = \sum_1^r c_j e_j$, then $x = \sum_1^r c_j v_j$ has $\|x\| = \|y\|$ and $Q^Tx = y$.

Comment: Let $Q = \begin{matrix} 1 0 0\\ 0 1 0 \end{matrix}$

Comment: That matrix doesn't have orthonormal columns.

Comment: Necessary for all this is $r \leq n$, otherwise $Q$ can't have orthonormal columns.

Comment: yes...got it..thanks. Clearly, $x = Qy$ is a solution with $||x|| = ||Qy|| = ||y||$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Recall that if $Q$ has orthonormal coloumns, then $Q^TQ=I$. Observe also that for all $x\in \mathbb R^r$, we have $\|Q^t Qx\|=\|x\|=\|Qx\|$. Can you finish it from here?